# How to retrieve the value of the attribute aria-label from element found using xpath as per the html using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, getattribute

I have the following HTML span:

```
<button class="coreSpriteHeartOpen oF4XW dCJp8">
    <span class="glyphsSpriteHeart__filled__24__red_5 u-__7" aria-label="Unlike"></span>
</button>
```

I also have a `webElement` representing the button containing this span that I have found using `xpath`. How can I retrieve the `aria-label` value (Unlike) from the element?

I tried to do:

```
btn = drive.find_element(By.xpath, "xpath") 
btn.get_attribute("aria-label")
```

but it returns nothing. How to retrieve the text value of an element 
with  'aria-label' attribute from the element object?

Comment: Can you post a more complete code/document example with the containing button and the code that creates `btn` in Python?

Comment: Is it enough now?

Comment: That helps, but how did you start the driver? I should have linked [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise I need to make assumptions about your code that may not be accurate. Even so, `"xpath"` looks like a pretty suspicious xpath to me.

Comment: share xpath locator you used

Comment: Could you explain to me how Instagram js detect which like button you clicked since in one page there are multiple like buttons with same class name ?

Answer (score 10):

`aria-label` is attribute of span element, not button.
You can get it like this:

```
btn = drive.find_element(By.xpath, "xpath") 
aria_label = btn.find_element_by_css_selector('span').get_attribute("aria-label")
```

Or if your goal is to find button with span contains attribute `aria-label="Unlike"`:

```
btn = drive.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[./span[@aria-label="Unlike"]]')
#you can add class to xpath also if you need
btn = drive.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[./span[@aria-label="Unlike"] and contains(@class,"coreSpriteHeartOpen)]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me in Java,

```
WebElement btnelement= driver.findElement(
                        By.xpath("//span[@aria-label='Unlike']"));
System.out.println("Attribute value is " + btnelement.getAttribute("value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and the *HTML* you have shared it seems that the element is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element, so to retrieve the attribute **aria-label** you have to induve *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element_xpath_you_found"))).get_attribute("aria-label"))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Like method
lov = el.find_element_by_class_name('glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9').click()  

# Unlike method
lov = el.find_element_by_class_name('glyphsSpriteHeart__filled__24__red_5').click()
```

I used these methods instead and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If xpath seems complicated, you can retrieve it with the class name and use the get_attribute method to access it.

```
value = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'glyphsSpriteHeart__filled__24__red_5 u-__7')
output = value.get_attribute("aria-label")
```